# Loop insertBefore adding a div before each current DIV

Tags: javascript

```js
const len = document.getElementById('parent').children.length
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 const div =  document.createElement("div"); 
 document.getElementById('parent').insertBefore(div, document.getElementById('parent').children[i])
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="asfd"></div>
  <div class="xcbs"></div>
  <div class="msfd"></div>
  <div class="powg"></div>
  <div class="ksle"></div>
</div>
```

This code returns

```
<div id="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="asfd"></div>
  <div class="xcbs"></div>
  <div class="msfd"></div>
  <div class="powg"></div>
  <div class="ksle"></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get an empty div before each current class

```
<div id="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div class="asfd"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="xcbs"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="msfd"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="powg"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="ksle"></div>
</div>
```

I can understand after inserting the first empty div, then the first empty div becomes the first child `[0]`. Is there a solution to achieve the goal? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because while you are iterating on elements you are adding it and length changes:

1 - first loop you add a div at 0

2 - second loop element that was at 0 now it's at 1 and you add a div before it

3 - and so on...

**Solution: foreach loop**
(used hr instead of div because is easier to view without styles)

```js
Array.from(document.getElementById('parent').children).forEach( (item, index) => {
 const div =  document.createElement("hr"); 
 document.getElementById('parent').insertBefore(div, item)
})
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="asfd">asfd</div>
  <div class="xcbs">xcbs</div>
  <div class="msfd">msfd</div>
  <div class="powg">powg</div>
  <div class="ksle">ksle</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem with the changing indexes, use a `querySelectorAll('#parent div')` and iterate over it using `for..of` instead of an index-based loop:

```js
for (const child of document.querySelectorAll('#parent div')) {
  document.getElementById('parent').insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), child);
}
```

```css
#parent div[class] {
  background-color: red;
  height: 4px;
}

#parent div:not([class]) {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="asfd"></div>
  <div class="xcbs"></div>
  <div class="msfd"></div>
  <div class="powg"></div>
  <div class="ksle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `document.getElementById('parent').children` return a live collection of children and `document.getElementById('parent').children[i]` will always be `<div class="asfd"></div>`, so you must make a copy of `document.getElementById('parent').children` outside of the `for` loop:

```js
const children = [...document.getElementById('parent').children];
for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
 const div =  document.createElement("div"); 
  div.innerHTML = i;
 document.getElementById('parent').insertBefore(div, children[i])
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="asfd">asfd</div>
  <div class="xcbs">xcbs</div>
  <div class="msfd">msfd</div>
  <div class="powg">powg</div>
  <div class="ksle">ksle</div>
</div>
```